# Why is the timeout on a windows udp receive socket always 500ms longer than set by SO_RCVTIMEO?

Tags: c++, sockets

Easy to reproduce, here is the psuedo code of what i am doing:

1. Set up a UDP socket
2. Set the timeout to a value (`Timeout set`)
3. Check the timeout that I set (`Timeout checked`)
4. Attempt to receive on that socket (when there is no traffic).
5. Time how long it takes to timeout. (`Time until Timeout`)

When I do this i get the following output:

```
Timeout set: 0.1s | Timeout checked: 0.1s | Time until timeout: 0.6s | difference: 0.5s
Timeout set: 0.2s | Timeout checked: 0.2s | Time until timeout: 0.7s | difference: 0.5s
Timeout set: 0.4s | Timeout checked: 0.4s | Time until timeout: 0.9s | difference: 0.5s
Timeout set: 0.8s | Timeout checked: 0.8s | Time until timeout: 1.3s | difference: 0.5s
Timeout set: 1.6s | Timeout checked: 1.6s | Time until timeout: 2.1s | difference: 0.5s
Timeout set: 3.2s | Timeout checked: 3.2s | Time until timeout: 3.7s | difference: 0.5s
```

**Why does the windows udp socket timeout always run 500ms longer than that set in setsockopt?**

Looking at [`setsockopt` here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) I can see no information about why this is occurring under the sections involving `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

---

*Code to reproduce:*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "winsock2.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        while (true);
    }

    sockaddr_in socketAddress = { 0 };
    socketAddress.sin_family = PF_INET;
    socketAddress.sin_port = htons(1010);
    socketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Create the socket
    SOCKET mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (!mSocket) { 
        printf("Socket failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        while (true);
    }

    //Bind
    if (bind(mSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddress, sizeof(socketAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        while (true);
    }

    // Receive nothing over several different set timeouts
    for (double timeout = 0.1; timeout < 4.0; timeout *= 2) {

        // Set timeout
        DWORD lBuffer[2] = { 0, 0 };
        int lSize;
        lBuffer[0] = static_cast<DWORD>(1000.0 * timeout);
        lSize = sizeof(DWORD);
        if (setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)lBuffer, lSize) != 0) {
            printf("Set socket option failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            while (true);
        }

        // Check that we get what we set.
        DWORD lBufferout[2] = { 0, 0 };
        if (getsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)lBufferout, &lSize) != 0) {
            printf("Set socket option failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            while (true);
        }

        // Receive and time
        char buffer[50];
        sockaddr_in senderAddr;
        int senderAddrSize = sizeof(senderAddr);

        auto s = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        int transferred = recvfrom(mSocket, (char*)buffer, 50, 0,
            (sockaddr*)&senderAddr, &senderAddrSize);

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - s).count() / 1000.0;

        std::cout << "Timeout set: " << timeout << "s | Timeout checked: " << lBufferout[0] / 1000.0 << "s | Time until timeout: " << duration << "s | difference: " << duration - timeout << "s\n";
    }

    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* This code is expecting there to be no traffic on port 1010. If this is not the case, change that number.

Comment: `int lBuffer[2]` should really be `DWORD lBuffer[2]`. It would be worth *getting* SO_RCVTIMEO after you set it, to see what the platform really set it to.

Comment: In general, as a rule of thumb, when a timeout is requested for some particular task, one can expect that the operation will wait until the requested action occurs "up to approximately" the requested time. One should never expect any kind of a real-time guarantee on the timeout, unless one uses a specially-designed [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) that explicitly gives you guarantees of this nature.

Comment: Could be [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  UPDATE - oops, you said udp... then this isn't it.

Comment: @EJP - Added this code and yeah its what i set. Also changed DWORD, but shouldn't matter in my case since `sizeof int == sizeof DWORD` on my system.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sure, but this is super consistently exactly 500ms out. Surely Windows would document this. Also people might want something like 10ms timeout. With that set, the minimum you can expect is 510ms until timeout. This could be heavily limiting on your application if you are trying to receive and timeout quickly.

Comment: Could be something entirely unrelated to sockets. Could be the Windows OS always schedules a task that was sleeping on an I/O event 500 ms after it wakes up and signals that it's ready to run. And as far as short timeouts, if one needs real time features like that, use a RTOS instead of Windows.

Comment: So to be clear, `lBuffer[0] == 100` after calling `getsockopt()`? And so on for the other iterations?

Comment: @EJP yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stated [here:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76620f6d-22b1-4872-aaf0-833204f3f867/minimum-timeout-value-for-sorcvtimeo?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

> There is an undocumented minimum limit of about 500mS on SO_RCVTIMEO.

It is likely that this is implemented by always adding 500ms to any value set for `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

Comment: This depends on the Windows version (or the version of some lib i dont know)
In Win10, its as expected, in Win7, its as described in the question. Strangely, the WSA version is the same on both OS (2.0 - `std::cout << "WSA version is " << wsaData.szDescription << std::endl;`)